# Graph and Network Library for Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, haskell-platform

Any suggestions for a good graph and network library for Haskell ?

I'm looking on functionality something like which [networkx](http://networkx.github.com/)  library has for Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found [fgl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl/) (also see [home page](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/haskell/)) quite easy to work with. I'm not familiar with networkx, so I don't know how it compares.

Answer (score 4):

There's a graph data-structure in the [containers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.2.1) package. You can view the interface for it [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Graph.html).

Additionally, you can search through all of the packages available on the haskell-platform or additional packages through Cabal using [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html)!

Comment: `containers` comes with GHC, and unless one knows very well what one's doing, one should stick with the version that came with GHC.

Comment: That's a good point, I'll remove the suggestion from my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's more than a year old question, but in case someone looks for the lib - [the igraph package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/igraph) provides the bindings to all functions about graph properties of the **igraph-C** library. It won't compile with the **igraph-C** versions newer than **0.6.5**, because the authors don't have time to maintain it, as Nils Schweinsberg said: Pull requests are wellcome. Also not all functions from the original library have the Haskell bindings, but one can write some using the **FFI**.

**fgl** is very beautiful library implementing the functional concept of inductive graphs, but it lacks the functionality of **the igraph library**: You can create directed/undirected weighted/unweighted graphs and have the algorithms implemented taking that into account.

**The igraph package** could be a very valuable library for the Haskell community if an experienced haskeller took care of it further.